# Using non-npm-package git submodules in npm packages

Tags: git, node.js, npm, git-submodules

How can I update **non-npm-package** [git-submodules](/questions/tagged/git-submodules) in my [npm](/questions/tagged/npm) package before install?

I'm using git and have a node.js module that depends on an external project also hosted in a git repository. I added the external project as a submodule and now I'm trying to make an npm package.

Since the external dependency is not an npm package (nor a node module), I think I can't use [`npm submodule`](https://npmjs.org/api/submodule.html) command, so I came up with [this](https://github.com/isaacs/octave-test/blob/master/package.json#L3) preinstall script in `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": { "preinstall" : "git submodule update --init"}
```

When I execute `npm install` in package directory, it works fine, but when I'm trying to install the package directly from my remote git repository or the tarball made with `npm pack`, I get the following error:

```
You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree.
```

I also tried (as the error message said):

```
"scripts": { "preinstall" : "cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) && git submodule update --init"}
```

This one doesn't show any errors but also doesn't update the submodule in package directory.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `npm` you download, once extracted, no longer contains the git information (no `.git` directory).

So no git command will work this way, but works locally because you have the git information.

As for a solution, you may have to create a script that does what `npm pack` does, but does not ignore submodules.

Not something I tried, but this script `https://github.com/Kentzo/git-archive-all` may be work out of the box with something like

```
git-archive-all --prefix package/ module.tgz
```

May require some tweaks...

Comment: Are you sure that the extracted package doesn't have `.git` directory? If so, I should be able to init a `git` repo there and since `.gitmodules` already exists, I can simply update git `submodules`.

Comment: I'm sure .git is not part fot the archive `npm pack` generates.  Running `git init` might work.  Worth a shot.  As an npm consumer, I'm not sure I'd like to get different code for a given version, though, but if this is for your own use, and you are fine with that, then sure.

Comment: I tried `git init`, and it initialized an empty git repository. But I had to add `submodules` manually again; It seems having `.gitmodules` in repository is not enough for `git` to recognize `submodules`. Finally I changed my package preinstall script to `git clone git://path/to/remote/repo` and also added the name of the remote repository directory to `.npmignore` and now everything is working fine.